# GREP Print Blank Lines For Non-Matches

Tags: sed, grep

I want to extract strings between two patterns with GREP, but when no match is found, I would like to print a blank line instead.

Input

```
This is very new
This is quite old
This is not so new
```

Desired Output

```
 is very 

 is not so
```

I've attempted:

grep -o -P '(?<=This).*?(?=new)'

But this does not preserve the second blank line in the above example. Have searched for over an hour, tried a few things but nothing's worked out.

Will happily used a solution in SED if that's easier!

Comment: Why do you use `email` if there is no `email` in your strings?

Comment: Sorry, difference between the example I've given here and the live command I'm trying. Will modify now...

Comment: But if you need to handle double quotes, you may run into issues. Please try not to oversimplify the content you have.

Comment: The main thing I'm struggling with is to preserve a blank line for non-matches. Giving an example input that clearly stated the scenario seemed better, but I'll take your advice into consideration in future.

Comment: So, is the problem solved or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='This is very new
This is quite old
This is not so new'
sed -En 's/.*This(.*)new.*|.*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/l8oLfH) yielding

```
 is very 

 is not so
```

*Details*:

- `E` - enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `n` - suppresses default line output
- `s/.*This(.*)new.*|.*/\1/` - finds any text, `This`, any text (captured into Group 1, `\1`, and then any text again, or the whole string (in `sed`, line), and replaces with Group 1 value.
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

And this is what you need for your actual data:

```sh
sed -En 's/.*"user_ip":"([^"]*).*|.*/\1/p'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/nGXJeD). The `[^"]*` matches zero or more chars other than a `"` char.

Comment: Since the alternation will always match is there a need for the `-n` option and the `p` flag?

Comment: @potong I have already optimized it twice, surely we can go on and remove what is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'This\\s+|\\s+new' 'NF==3{print $2;next} NF!=3{print ""}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -F'This\\s+|\\s+new' 'NF==3{print $2;next} {print ""}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `This\\s+` OR `\\s+new` as field separators for all the lines of Input_file. Then in main program checking condition if NF(number of fields) are 3 then print 2nd field (where `next` will take cursor to next line). In another condition checking if `NF`(number of fields) is NOT equal to `3` then simply print a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

sed:

```sh
sed -E '
    /This.*new/! s/.*//
    s/.*This(.*)new.*/\1/
' file
```

1. first line: lines **not** matching "This.*new", remove all characters leaving a blank line
2. second lnie: lines matching the pattern, keep only the "middle" text

   - this is **not** the pcre *non-greedy* match: the line

     ```
     This is new but that is not new
     ```

     will produce the output

     ```
      is new but that is not
     ```

To continue to use PCRE, use perl:

```sh
perl -lpe '$_ = /This(.*?)new/ ? $1 : ""' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -E 's/.*This(.*)new.*|.*/\1/' file
```

If the first match is made, the line is replace by everything between `This` and `new`.

Otherwise the second match will remove everything.

N.B. The substitution will always match one of the conditions. The solution was suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew.